# Paste Tickmarks (pictures) into Excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, bitmap

I am trying to add some custom tickmarks into an Addin and the way I have it set up right now is they are simply unhiding the addin worksheet and copy/pasting the tickmark object from the addin over to the active workbook. However this process is causing the addin workbook to flash across the screen for a millisecond. Is there a better way of setting this up? The flashing is annoying. Additionally I think it is probably possible to call the .bmp objects directly from a database rather than storing them in excel. Do you have any suggestions on how to prevent the screen flashing when the macro is run?

```
Sub Circle1()
'
' Circle1 Macro
' Circle with a 1 in it
'
'
WB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
WS = ActiveSheet.Name
AC = ActiveCell.AddressLocal

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Windows("toolbar.xlsm").Visible = True
    Workbooks("toolbar.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 2")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(WB).Activate
    Workbooks(WB).Worksheets(WS).Range(AC).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("toolbar.xlsm").Visible = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot test it, but couldn’t you avoid all that Select/Activate? Like Workbooks("toolbar.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 2")).Copy
    Workbooks(WB).Worksheets(WS).Range(AC).Paste

Answer (score 1):

You should not select shapes prior to copying, the same goes for the source workbook.

Try something like this (simplified by only pointing to the shape, not the shaperange):

```
Workbooks("toolbar.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Picture 2").copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I guess you could keep screenupdating off if you are copying several pictures, but the need will be lessen since the only flicker should be shapes popping ut, which is kind of pleasant.

Comment: Thanks Loveburner. I tried to avoid selecting the Shape range before but it threw an error the first time. Looks like it is working now though, I guess user error.

Answer (score 0):

I realize your question is specific to images, but depending on **your *"tick mark needs"***, perhaps Unicode symbols would be a simpler *(ie., copy & paste) *alternative to dealing with individual images.

## ✅  ✓  ✔  ⍻  ☑  ✗  ×  x  X  ✕  ☓  ✖  ✗  ✘  ❎  ✖  ❌  ×  ╳  ☓

<sup>(These are all characters, not images.)</sup>

Unicode v.10 has over **136,000** characters available... something for everyone!

---

### More Information:

- Wikipedia : [Tick Mark (Check Mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tick_mark)
- Wikipedia : [List of Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)
- Unicode.org : [Unicode® 10.0.0](http://unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/)
- MSDN : [Chr / ChrW functions in Excel VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264465(v=office.14).aspx)
- [Unicode and VBA’s ChrW() and AscW() functions](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/11/19/unicode-and-vbas-chrw-and-ascw-functions/)